# Python - List of indices of elements of another list that match a condition

Tags: python, list, indexing, conditional-statements, sublist

It seems fairly easy but I'm kind of stuck on this one.
I have a list of logical values, e.g.:

```
a=[True, False, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]
```

and I want to construct another list containing (in sub-lists) the indices of 'a' that are 'True', with successive indices put in the same sub-list. So, for the above example the answer would be:

```
[[0], [2,3], [6,7,8]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), a one-liner is possible:

```
from itertools import groupby
[[i for i, _ in g] for k, g in groupby(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1]) if k]
```

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein,

```
>>> a = [True, False, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(v) for k,v in groupby([_ if a[_] else None for _ in range(len(a)) ], lambda x: not x is None) if k]
[[0], [2, 3], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

pure Python, no libs:

```
a=[True, False, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]

indcs = [i for i, b in enumerate(a) if b]

if indcs:
    o, s = [], [indcs[0]]
    for a, b in zip(indcs, indcs[1:] + [indcs[-1]]):
        if b-a == 1:
            s.append(b)
        else:
            o.append(s)
            s = [b]
else:
    o = []

o    
Out[32]: [[0], [2, 3], [6, 7, 8]]
```